# Error in fbOAuth using Rfacebook

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to extract data from face-book. I created app_id and app_secret from developer side using http://thinktostart.com/analyzing-facebook-with-r/ blogs.

when I run following code

```
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="1696409453911351", app_secret="7c45ba992e869613b31819509824e06d", extended_permissions = TRUE)
```

then I copied "http://localhost:1410/" and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings then hit enter but

I got Error which image uploaded
[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advanced

Comment: I do not want any thing from your end. I reviewed your question and edited its part so added comment as improved your question formatting.

Comment: The `read_stream` permission doesn't exist anymore.